# Find the absolute path for the root of the codebase

Tags: server, apache2, php, paths, aws

I need to find the absolute path for the root of the codebase.... is that a way to get it out easily??

I have a website that runs on on EC2 AWS/Ubuntu written at 95% in PHP and is linked with plesk. I use plesk because it keeps the management easy for me.
Really losing my mind to get it. Based on this info can someone help?

Thanks for any support!

Answer (score 0):

First, I think this question might get better answers on StackOverflow.com as it sounds related to software development and programming, not specifically Ubuntu or Debian systems.

To find the absolute path of the code base really depends on what the deployment mechanism is for the application. For example, a simple deployment mechanism might do a `git clone` operation or unzipping of a `tar.gz` file to a specific directory. If that is done, you have your absolute path just by looking at the destination.

I'll also say, as a common practice with PHP apps, the root codebase is often either the directory where `index.php` is located, or the parent directory of that. Not always, but I'd say 95% of use cases (depends on what framework).